# Failed to retrieve data from the database [Database Vendor Code: 8169]

Tags: crystal-reports, database-connection, crystal-reports-server

My 2013 Crystal Report suddenly gave me this error:

> Failed to retrieve data from the database. Details: [Database Vendor Code: 8169]

I created a new database connection and changed the connection, and when I click *Verify Database* it tells me the database is up to date. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Even though the database connection is okay, your query may be bad, or there is some other database component making the data retrieval fail. Easiest way is to run the query or queries in the Crystal Report in a database client tool. For example, with Oracle, you can use SQL Developer to run the query manually.

SQL Server should have its own client tool as well.

http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/errors/12/0/en/html/topic180.html